# How to specialize a template constructor templated?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, data-structures

How do I make the specialization on a template constructor?
For the purpose of better understandings, I will bring an example of code:

```
template<typename T>
class Stack {
  private:
    int nelem;
    int size;
    vector<T> stack;

  public:
    ~Stack();
    Stack<T>(int t);
    void push(T data);
    T pop();
    T top();
    int getPosTop(){return (nelem--);};
    void cleanStack(){nelem = 0;};
    bool StackEmpty(){ return (nelem == 0);};
    bool StackFull(){ return (nelem == size);};
};


template <typename T>       // constructor definition here
Stack<T>::Stack<T>(int t){
  size = t;
  nelem = 0;
};

int main(){



return 0;
}
```

It came with lots of errors. 
Then, I read on another post, some suggestion , which was replacing

```
template <typename T>
    Stack<T>::Stack<T>(int t){
```

to

```
template <typename T> template <typename T> Stack<T>::Stack<T> (int t){
```

Which was not sufficient.

What am I missing? And, what is the thinking behind it?

Comment: You can't specialize constructor because constructor is not a template. It's a non template method of a class template.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to know how to specialize just the constructor `Stack<T>::Stack`
for particular values of `T`. You do it as illustrated:-

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Stack {
private:
    std::size_t nelem;
    std::size_t size;
    std::vector<T> stack;

public:
    ~Stack(){};
    Stack<T>(std::size_t n);
    void push(T data);
    T pop();
    T top();
    std::size_t getPosTop(){return (nelem--);};
    void cleanStack(){nelem = 0;};
    bool StackEmpty(){ return (nelem == 0);};
    bool StackFull(){ return (nelem == size);};
};

template <typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(std::size_t t){
    size = t;
    nelem = 0;
    std::cout << "Constructing a `Stack<T>`\n";
}

template <>
Stack<std::string>::Stack(std::size_t t){
    size = t;
    nelem = 0;
    std::cout << "Constructing a `Stack<T>` with `T` = `std::string`\n";
}

template <>
Stack<int>::Stack(std::size_t t){
    size = t;
    nelem = 0;
    std::cout << "Constructing a `Stack<T>` with `T` = `int`\n";
}

int main() {
    Stack<float> sf{2};
    Stack<int> si{3};
    Stack<std::string> ss{4};
    sf.cleanStack();
    si.cleanStack();
    ss.cleanStack();
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs:-

```
Constructing a `Stack<T>`
Constructing a `Stack<T>` with `T` == `int`
Constructing a `Stack<T>` with `T` == `std::string`
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b333b4a624599a82)

Answer (score 2):

Only your class is template, not your constructor, you should simply use

```
template <typename T>
Stack<T>::Stack(int t){ /*...*/ }
```

If you want to specialize your constructor for `Stack<char>`, it would be

```
template <>
Stack<char>::Stack(int t){ /*...*/ }
```

Comment: But, what if I wanted to create different constructors for different types of data? Because, what you said means that  the line  ``Stack<T>(int t);`` is not ok

Comment: You'll have to expand on that @Homunculus . Different in what way?

Comment: @user4581301 If my Stack is of int, the constructor does ...(1), or if std::string does ...(2). An example could also be, if it is a Stack of **strings**, the constructor allocate memory, but if **int**, not.

Comment: Then, you can use specialization and depending of your need, you can specialize just few method or the whole class.

Comment: @Jarod42 but that is what my question is about. How to specialize the constructor, but not the whole class, if the types are different from stack to stack. That is what I was trying to do before the class definition, code example